# Unable to launch Windows 7 (32 bit) with bcdedit /debug on Option

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, windbg

I am readiing books and articles on Windows internals. I wanted to launch Kernel Debugger in WinDBG in Windows 7 (32 bit) machine. I tried enabling the machine for Debug by setting `bcdedit /debug /on`.

After restarting the machine, it just hangs. Then turning off the `bcdedit /debug /off` in safe mode, make my machine work normally. I searched for the cause in the Internet and stopped Skype as suggested in one of the articles that said is one of the cause of hang.

Doing all these still does not make my machine work in Debug mode. Can anyone help me on this?
Its so frustrating that I have books and videos in which they do kernel debugging in so simple way and I am struggling to launch the debugger :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is your OS is waiting for being debug, you should use a debugger to attach it and you can see why you OS hang when start up and what's going wrong.That's is the meaning of Debugging :)

Before you're very  familiar with the kernel debugging,you should install a virtual machine running Windows 7 on it and take every experiment on that.In that case, you wouldn't take the risk of massing up you machine and it's easy to restore fresh snapshot if some thing wrong.you can follow this Instruction:

[How to Debug Kernel-Mode Windows 
Drivers Using VirtualBox and WinDBG](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jdl5225/blogs/eportfolio/Instruction_Set.pdf)

Comment: +1 - Much easier to get started with kernel debugging is to use livekd from sysinternals.

Comment: Hi Lieven, I tried running LiveKd as well. I get error telling it cannot get symbols for ntoskrnl.exe. I checked for the environment variable for the path, everything was correctly set. But I still see the issue. :(  Now I will try creating a virtual machine and do. Thanks theliam, I wanted to keep the options last for creating the virtual machine or debugging another machine by wire. But looks like that is the only way left for me